# How to get variable which is not defined in the form using php?

Tags: php

I have a script as attached snap.

```
<?php
$mailid = "abc@xyz.com";
?>
<form name = "Register" method = "post" action = "test.php">
<table width="50%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td align=center><strong>Enter your details to register </strong></td></tr></table>
<table width="50%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">   

<tr>
<td align=center>Name</td><td align=center>:</td><td align=center><input type = 'text' id='name' name ='name' ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align=center>User Name</td><td align=center>:</td><td align=center><input type = 'text' name = 'uname' ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align=center>Password</td><td align=center>:</td><td align=center><input type = 'password' name = 'password' ></td></tr>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

In test.php i can get name, username and password. but how can i pass "mailid" to test.php by clicking Register button?

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it in an hidden field,

```
<input type='hidden' name='mailid' value="<?php echo $mailid; ?>" >
```

Or alternate you can use SESSION,

```
$_SESSION['mailid'] = $mailid;
```

Answer (score 0):

That would do. Place this inside the form.

```
<?php echo $mailid  ?> // will help you get the value.

<input  style='display:none' name="mailid" value='<?php echo $mailid  ?>' />
```

**In other php file.**

```
$value = $_POST['mailid'];
```

value contains now your value.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="hidden" name="email2" value="abc@xyz.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use form hidden field.
Before you submit button input use following code

```
<input type='hidden' name='mailid' value='<?php echo $mailid; ?>' \>
```

Now when you submit form you will get hidden value in

```
$_POST['mailid']
```